# Ubuntu 14.04.2 Menu bar and Launcher Missing

Tags: 14.04, launcher, menu

As you may have gathered from the title of this question, my menu bar and launcher are missing from my account.

It started when I tried to download unity (the mobile platform development tool) through wine, which failed, and then I (in the midst of my forgetfulness of how ubuntu is unity based) tried to remove it through terminal by typing:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity
```

And my menu bar and launcher have been missing ever since.

I've tried to fix it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity
```

to no avail, and I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

to which I received the error:

```
E: Command line option --reinstall not understood
```

Random Notes about this issue:

- It is only on my account (the only other being Guest Session, which appears perfectly fine)
- I can still open and use the applications on my desktop (of which there are select few)
- I can open the rest of my applications by creating a folder, double clicking on it and then hunting for it in my file system, which is a royal pain
- Of the applications I open through that loophole, They cannot be moved around or resized by dragging their border
- There is some space to the right of my desktop which I can hide the mouse or move Chrome into, and which is at least as wide as my desktop

Comment: `apt-get --reinstall` isn't the correct format. It's `apt-get install --reinstall`. See if that fixes it. Also, did you reboot after you installed Unity again?

Comment: Yes I've rebooted and I am about to try apt-get install --reinstall as you suggest. Also, I neglected to mention I also tried sudo service lightdm restart, which also failed.

Comment: export DISPLAY=:0   
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
setsid unity
http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/290376#290376

Comment: @Aravinda Thanks! Not that particular solution, but the main one on that page seemed to work! Thank you!